# Find parameters such that the function image is a given interval.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, quadratics

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},f(x)=\frac {ax+b}{x^2+1}.$ Find $a,b$ such that $\Im_f=[-3,1].$

My attempt:

Found $f'(x)=-\frac {ax^2+2bx+a}{(x^2+1)^2}$ but can't solve the equation: $ax^2+2bx+a=0.$ To find points of extrema. Can you give me a hint with another approach? Or how can I use this one better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you solve the equation $$-3 ={ax+b\over x^2+1}$$ on $x$ then discriminant of $$3x^2+ax+b +3=0$$ must be $0$ (if you draw a line $y=-3$ it must touch a graph of $f$), so $$\boxed{ a^2-12(b+3)=0}$$ The same holds for $$1 ={ax+b\over x^2+1}\implies x^2-ax+1-b=0$$ so $$\boxed{a^2-4(1-b)=0}$$

You get a system to solve...

Comment: Why $x = - 3$ in $ax^2+2bx+a=0$?  Should some value of $x_0$, where $x_0$ is the solution to that equation and $f(x_0)=-3$??

Comment: Aren't they value of $f$? and not of $x$?

Comment: Why the discriminant of these $2$ must be $0$? What if there was not a $polynomial$ of degree $2$ and there was some other function? How could I solve it then? still does the derivative of the function $f$ helps me somehow in this problem?

Comment: Shouldn't it be there $3x^2+ax-b+3$?

Comment: Done, $a=-2\sqrt{3}, b = -2$ or $a=2\sqrt{3}, b = -2$.. if i'm right... can you explain more about "if you draw a line at $x=3$"?

Comment: I meant $y=-3$...

Comment: And my other question is still up if you can answer it about the solution using the derivative

Comment: Hmm, I see, if let say the *interval* was not closed and it was $(-3,1)$ Would this method still work?

Comment: You can solve it but youl get 4 equation and four unknown. $f(x_1)=-3$ and $f'(x_1)=0$. And the same $f(x_2)=1$ and $f'(x_2)=0$

Comment: Where $x_1,x_2$ are?

Comment: $\frac{a}{2}, \frac {-a}{6}$

Comment: valuest for $f$ in which it takes min=-3 and max =1. you have to find them in other to get $a$ and $b$